# Why can't ld ignore an unused unresolved symbol?

Tags: c, linux, linker, undefined-symbol, lto

Consider the following source files:

**a.c**:

```
extern int baz();

int foo() { return 123; }
int bar() { return baz() + 1; }
```

**b.c:**

```
extern int foo();

int main() { return foo(); }
```

Now, when I try to build a program using these sources, here's what happens:

```
$ gcc -c -o a.o a.c
$ gcc -c -o b.o b.c
$ gcc -o prog a.o b.o
/usr/bin/ld: a.o: in function `bar':
a.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `baz'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is on Devuan GNU/Linux Chimaera, with GNU ld 2.35.2, GCC 10.2.1.

Why does this happen?  I mean, one does not need any complex optimization to know that `baz()` is not really needed in `foo()` - ld naturally notices this at some point - e.g. when finishing its traversal of `foo()` without noticing a location where `baz()` is used.

Now, you could say "einpoklum, you didn't ask the compiler to go to any trouble for you" - and that's fair, I guess, but even if I use `-O3` with these instructions, I get the same error.

Note: with LTO and  optimization enabled, we can circumvent this issue:

```
$ gcc -c -flto -O1 -o b.o b.c
$ gcc -c -flto -O1 -o a.o a.c
$ gcc -o prog -O1 -flto a.o b.o
$ /prog ; echo $?;
123
```

Comment: enable dead code removal and use -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

Comment: @0___________: 1. But dead code will be removed anyway when linking, won't it? It's not like the linker puts _all_ of the library in the executable... or does it? 2. Why the f*** do I need to use arcane `-f` switches for something trivial to happen? :-(

Comment: @ Does it work?

Comment: @0___________: I'm not sure what you mean by "enable dead code removal". Will `-O3` take care of it? Also, are these switches for compilation or for linking? When I use `-O3 -flto -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections` with all gcc invocations, it doesn't work.

Comment: The *compiler* does not know `bar` is not going to be used and is placing it into the common `.text` section. The linker knows, but it cannot eliminate code with function granularity, it can remove sections. This is why each function needs to be placed in a separate section for that.

Comment: @einpoklum `--gc-sections`

Comment: @EugeneSh.: "it cannot eliminate code with function granularity" - 1. Why not? 2. So what? It can keep `bar()` with its unresolved symbol in the final executable and none will be the wiser. Or it can satisfy the unresolved symbol with a stub, or with the `exit()` function etc.

Comment: @0___________:  1. `--gc-sections` where? 2. There is no such option.

Comment: it is `ld` option

Comment: @einpoklum Can't tell the exact reason, but it is a limitation pretty common to different compilers I am familiar with.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: See edited comment.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It speeds up the process. Sections are marked as hot or cold. Simply elimination is possible without special offset tables magic. Single-pass is possible

Comment: @0___________: 1. If the sped-up process fails, one should go the slow way. 2. A linker  switch could say `--dont-speed-up-the-process`.

Comment: @einpoklum it is not needed complication for no reason. You simply need to know your tools. Everything is explained in the documentation

Comment: Someone has to decide on what the default behaviour is. They've hopefully made that decision based on usage and implementation considerations. You personally may prefer different defaults but if the defaults were done your way someone else would want the other way.

Comment: @kaylum: I don't mind this not being default behavior, but it should be single switch with an easy-to-understand name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `gcc` and binutils `ld` to build your programs you need to place functions in separate sections. It is archived by `-fdata-sections` &  `-ffunction-sections` command line options.

Same with data. Then if you do not want dead code to be included in your executable you need to enable it by using `--gc-sections` `ld` option.

Putting this all together:

```
$ gcc -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -c -o a.o a.c
$ gcc -c -o b.o b.c
$ gcc -Wl,--gc-sections -o prog a.o b.o
$ /prog ; echo $?
123
```

If you want to enable it by default simple build `GCC` with those options enabled.

Comment: Edited to make the suggestions more explicit.

Comment: The suggestion about "building GCC yourself" is only relevant if you're the person doing the build. If you're a library author, you don't get to control the compiler build options...

Comment: @einpoklum I actually quite often build the toolchain from the sources. gcc is open source :)

Answer (score 2):

In a “plain” traditional compilation of this code:

```
extern int baz();

int foo() { return 123; }
int bar() { return baz() + 1; }
```

the compiler creates one object module that contains the code of both routines along with definitions for symbols `foo` and `bar` and a reference to `baz`. There is nothing to tell the linker where the code belonging to `foo` begins and ends, where the code belonging to `bar` begins and ends or even that any given piece of code—or any given byte in the object module—belongs only to one of `foo` or `bar`. Had I written in assembly and assembled to make an object module, I could have included code in `foo` that jumped into `bar` (using only hard-coded offsets calculated by the assembler and not revealed in any symbols visible to the linker) or vice-versa.

So the linker has no way of knowing that `foo` and `bar` can be separated.

Later, a protocol was created for the compiler to keep functions separated and to provide sufficient information in the object modules that the linker could determine where they were separated and to tell the linker it was okay to separate functions. When the options for that are enabled, the linker may be able to include `foo` in the program without including `bar`.

That this feature is not yet the default in the tools is a matter of legacy in various build systems and projects, inertia, and current practice.

Comment: OP can build gcc himself with these options enabled by default if he wishes to.

Comment: Interesting! 1. But doesn't that make linking a lot slower, when using large libraries? I mean, if my library has 100 functions but my program has 1, I would need to do 100x external symbol resolutions than I would do if I could work on just the function I use. And I may be able to entirely avoid reading some objects and libraries altogether. 2. What is that protocol called? 3. Can't you enable this option with a compiler switch?